# Can I install just the client for SVN on Centos?

Tags: svn, centos-5

I want to install just the subversion client on a Centos machine so that I can use it for version control of config files, etc. All the instructions are for installing the full thing, including Apache mods, etc.

Is there a way of installing just a command line client?

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to just do:

```
yum install subversion
```